# Computing a series of matrix power - matrix products

Tags: algorithms, numerical-algorithms, matrix-multiplication

Assuming we have two dense matrices $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times m}, B \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$, is there a smart way to compute all entries of the series $A^1 B, A^2 B, A^3 B, \dots, A^k B$ up to some k? In general the matrices are arbitrary, but I'd be willing to accept some not-super-restrictive structure if that would make the problem easier, e.g. diagonalizable or PSD.

The minimally-smart way would be to just do it incrementally, which leads to $O ( k \max(m,n)^\omega )$, where $2 \le \omega \le 2.373$ is the matrix multiplication constant. I'm curious if there's some structure we could exploit to make that cheaper. I'm interested in practical applications so even non-asymptotic improvements could be fine.

Comment: The minimally smart way would be more like $O(k \max(m, n)^{\omega})$ where $\omega \approx 2.3728596$ is the matrix multiplication constant.

Comment: Sorry, I brought this on myself by posting this in CS stackexchange. You're of course right in general. I was assuming using this in practice with non-astronomical matrices where smart matrix multiplication would be slower. I'm going the question to make this clearer.

Comment: Why do you need $A^1 B, A^2 B, A^3 B, \dots, A^k B$ (if it's not a secret)? I'm asking because e.g. for diagonalizable matrix you can compute them as $S^{-1} (\Lambda^k (S B))$, where $S$ is basis transformation and $\Lambda$ is the diagonal form. But it doesn't improve anything so far, since you need to multiply every result by $S^{-1}$. However, depending on your application, you may not need to.